# inotifywait not detecting new directories

Tags: bash, inotify

The script below watches for close_write events in the TARGET directory and does something with the file

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=/home/*/ftp/files

inotifywait -m -r -e close_write $TARGET |
        while read directory action file
        do
                if [[ "$file" =~ .*jpg$ ]] || [[ "$file" =~ .*mp4$ ]]
                then
                        # do sth with the file
                fi
        done
```

So right now it is correctly watching for close_write events for files under e.g. `/home/sammy/ftp/files` and `/home/neo/ftp/files`.

The problem I'm facing is once a new user created, let's say mike, then the watch seems to no longer be working and I will have to re-execute the script so that it will *know* about the new user's path, i.e. the nohup process needs to be killed and be ran again.

Is there any way for inotifywait to know about newly created directories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `-r` it automatically finds new directories created under the ones it's watching. But here, it gets the paths `/home/sammy/ftp/files` and `/home/neo/ftp/files` (etc.), and `/home/mike` isn't under either of them, so it won't be detected. (Remember, it's the shell that expands the glob `/home/*/ftp/files` before `inotifywait` even runs.)

In principle, you could watch the whole of `/home` and manually ignore anything that wasn't in `/home/*/ftp/files`. But that would create piles of watches and produce loads of unwanted events.

A better idea might be to watch `/home` in addition to the `/home/*/ftp/files` directories, and to restart the watch when seeing a new subdirectory added under `/home`. If any new users always get the `ftp/files` directory created immediately, that shouldn't be too bad. You should probably explicitly wait for the new `ftp/files` directory to appear though, so that you don't fall into the race where your script resets the `inotifywait` before the new `ftp/files` is created, thus missing it.

(Though restarting `inotifywait` creates a window where a new file could be created, with the script missing it. Stuff like this would probably be safer to do with some programming language that supports inotify directly.)

A completely different approach would be to change the directory structure so that instead of `/home/$user/files/ftp`, the related stuff would be in  `/srv/ftp/$user`. Then you could just add a watch on `/srv/ftp`, automatically catching new users without problems.